# Position UIButton 20px from the right of screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I was hoping this would be really easy, and I'm sure it is, but I simply can't make anything work.

I've added a `viewForHeaderInSection` to my `tableView`. I've declared the `UIView()` variable, and also added a `UIButton`:

```
let myHeaderView = UIView()
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

Everything works and displays, but what I want, is for the button to be positioned 20px from the right hand side of the view/screen.

In my button code, I've used:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, myHeaderView.frame.height / 2, 90, 30)
```

Using `0` positions the button to the left of the screen. I want it positioned from the right of the screen.

This seems like it should be incredibly simple, and I hope it is, but no one seems to mention how to do it online, and anything I try just doesn't work.

**Example of what I need**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the button's x position taking into account the width of the screen and then taking the width of your button off this value and then taking off 20px padding:

Frame values go x, y, width, height.

So you want screen width minus 110 (which is button width plus padding):

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 110, 0, 90, 30)
```

This will position your 90px width button 20px from the right edge of the screen. :)

Also, make sure you are putting the x value as the first parameter as it goes x, y, width, height.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but that starts the positioning from the left of the screen, and then just hides the button offscreen by 110px. I would like the button to be positioned from the right of the screen/UIView...

Comment: x values always start from the left, I'm saying this is fine and you can just calculate the x position by getting the screen/width and subtracting the button width to position it on the right edge, as you want right?